# Apply IsNull function on a date column (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I am trying to apply the `IsNull` function to a column of a datatype `date`.
What am trying to do is, to replace the word `NULL` with an empty string (actual null value) when retrieving the data

The code am using is;

```
Select 
    ISNULL("UPDATE_DT", '')
from 
    MyTable
```

I have also tried

```
Select 
    ISNULL("UPDATE_DT", 0)
from 
    MyTable
```

The error am getting is

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parse error at line: 4, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'from'.

Comment: why do you use quotes to select a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the column as an empty string rather than "NULL", you need to convert the output to a string.  To control the format, use `convert()`:

```
select coalesce(convert(varchar(10), update_dt, 121), '')
. . .
```

Then use `coalesce()` (or if you must, `isnull()`) to replace the `NULL` value with another string.

Comment: I was trying something similar, i just never reached the right syntax, appreciate it.